# Using IN within a CASE statement without repeating input expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

When using a `CASE` statement, I realise that as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) I can either use a simple `CASE` expression, with an `input_expression` and pairs of `when_expression` and `result_expression` values (assume in these examples that values in `myField` are always positive integers):

```
CASE [input_expression]
    WHEN [when_expression] THEN [result_expression]
    ...
    ELSE [result_expression]
END


CASE myField
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Two'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Three'
    ELSE 'More than three'
END
```

or I can use a searched `CASE` expression, with pairs of `Boolean_expression` and `result_expression` values:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Boolean_expression] THEN [result_expression]
    ...
    ELSE [result_expression]
END


CASE 
    WHEN myField = 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN myField = 2 THEN 'Two'
    WHEN myField = 3 THEN 'Three'
    ELSE 'More than three'
END
```

I also know that I can use the `IN` operator as part of any `Boolean_expression` when writing a searched `CASE` expression:

```
CASE
    WHEN myField IN (1,2) THEN 'One or two'
    WHEN myField = 3 THEN 'Three'
    ELSE 'More than three'
END
```

What would be really useful would be to be able to use the `IN` operator when writing a simple `CASE` expression, like:

```
CASE myField
    WHEN IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Between one and three'
    WHEN IN (4,5,6) THEN 'Between four and six'
    WHEN IN (7,8,9) THEN 'Between seven and nine'
    ELSE 'More than nine'
END
```

But this will not run and gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

Obviously my example above is contrived, but **is there any way to write a simple `CASE` expression and also use the `IN` operator?**

I understand from reading the syntax on MSDN that it appears this is not possible, because of how the simple `CASE` expression is formed - comparing the `input_expression` to each `when_expression` for equality - but I just wondered if there's any kind of way to achieve what I'm asking as it would be a handy to save writing the same field name over and over again within each `WHEN` clause of a searched `CASE` expression.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't have syntax like that. Closest it gets is your third example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The documentation differentiates between the *when_expression* and the *Boolean_expression*. The *when_expression* always uses the equality operator.

Aaron Bertrand described this in his [Dirty Secrets of the CASE expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) that an expression like this

```
SELECT CASE @variable
  WHEN 1 THEN 'foo'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'bar'
END
```

evaluates to

```
SELECT
  WHEN @variable = 1 THEN 'foo'
  WHEN @variable = 2 THEN 'bar'
END
```

So there's no way to replace the comparison operator using the *when_expression*. This is only possible with the *Boolean_expression* like you already mentioned:

```
SELECT
  WHEN @variable IN (1,2) THEN 'foo'
  WHEN @variable in (3,4) THEN 'bar'
END
```